# Someone explain What goes on in the 2nd line of code? Why does map function use name while the variable name is names? Flutter/dart

Tags: dart

```dart
final names = ['Max', 'Manu', 'Julie'];
final result = names.map((name) => Text(name)).toList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map()` expects as an argument a *function*. In this case,

> `(name) => Text(name)`

is an *anonymous function*, i.e. it is not bound to a name. Similarly to how you can have values like `3` or `"a string"` without binding them to a variable, so they have no "name", you can have unnamed functions.

The syntax of the anonymous function is `(<arguments>) => <what to do with the arguments>`. This function has one argument, `name`, and it takes it and makes a `Text` with it.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in a previous answer, the `map` method expects a `Function` as it's argument.

Imagine the code was like this:

```dart
Text stringToText(String name){
  return Text(name);
}

final names = ['Max', 'Manu', 'Julie'];
final result = names.map(stringToText).toList();
```

This makes it pretty clear. Each String in the `names` list will be passed into the `stringToText` function, and a `Text` object is cranked out. The `stringToText` function says, "whatever my input is, I'm gonna call that '*name*'. Whenever I use '*name*', I'm referring to my input value".

But, this is only nice and easy to follow because the function that we're passing has a name.

As stated in a previous answer, you can create an *anonymous function* - a function with no name.

If it's a single line that returns something, like in our case, you can use a "fat-arrow" function, like this:
`(inputVariableName) => OutputObjectProducer(inputVariableName)`

If it's more than one line, you can create it in a standard form, but with no name and no listed return type, like so (you can even leave out the types of the parameters because the compiler can already tell what the types are supposed to be!):

```dart
(inputVariableName) {
  var someNeededVariable = someCalculation();
  //... some other stuff here
  return OutputObjectProducer(someNeededVariable);
}
```

You could even create the function as an Object like so:
`Function stringToText = (String name) => Text(name);`

As of the time of this writing, you can't pass a constructor as a Function reference even if the signature is a match.

I hope this helped clear things up: the name `name` is a newly defined parameter for an anonymous function defined within the call to `.map`

Comment: Beautifully explained! Thank you so much